# Should viewport units be responsive in the shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, css, safari, shadow-dom, viewport-units

In Safari, I don't think viewport units (such as `vw`) applied to elements in the shadow DOM actually respond to changes to the viewport.  Should they?

In the demo below, the light blue `<main>` element and the danger striped `<div>` both have their widths set to `50vw`.  In Chrome, Firefox, Edge, and Opera, these elements have the same size as I grow and shrink the viewport, while in Safari, the `<div>` stays whatever size it started at.

```js
const shadow = document.querySelector('.shadow-root').attachShadow({ mode: 'open' });

const style = document.createElement('style');
style.innerText = `
div {
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100px;
  background-image: repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg, #333 0, #333 10px, #fc0 10px, #fc0 20px);
}`;

shadow.appendChild(style);
shadow.appendChild(document.createElement('div'));
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 50vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<main class="shadow-root"></main>
```

Answer (score 0):

YES, they SHOULD.

This is a MAJOR failure on Safari's part.

Workaround: It is possible to achieve dynamic sizing by using rem units in shadow font-size and setting font-size to a vh/vw unit on html.